# Orthogonal projection to symmetric matrices with bounded eigenvalues

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, positive-definite, projection

Let $0<a<b$,  $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the set of all $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices, and $\mathcal{V} \subset\mathbb{S}^n $ be the set of symmetric matrices such that $aI\le X \le b I$, where $\le $ means the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order).
Consider the orthogonal projection  $\Pi:\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathcal{V}$ such that
for all $A\in \mathbb{S}^n$,
$$
\Pi(A)=\arg\min_{X\in \mathcal{V}}\|X-A\|^2.
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ indicates the Frobenius norm or spectral norm.

I was wondering whether there is  a simple procedure to evaluate $\Pi$ (for one of the above matrix norms).
Can the projection operator $\Pi$ be expressed in terms of projecting the corresponding eigenvalues of $A$?

As shown  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436094/find-the-matrix-projection-of-a-symmetric-matrix-onto-the-set-of-symmetric-posit), the claim holds if  $a=0$ and $b=\infty$. The argument relies on any positive semidefinite matrices have nonnegative diagonals, which can not be easily extended to general $a,b$.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246047

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still reduce the problem to diagonals. For the Frobenius norm, von-Neumann's trace inequality gives

$$
\|X - A\|_F^2 = \|X\|_F^2 + \|A\|_F^2 - 2 \langle X, A\rangle \geq
\|X\|_F^2 + \|A\|_F^2 - 2 \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i(X)\sigma_i(A) \\
= \| \Sigma_X \|_F^2 + \| \Sigma_A \|_F^2 - 2 \langle \Sigma_A, \Sigma_X \rangle = \| \Sigma_X - \Sigma_A \|_F^2
$$

where $\sigma_i(\cdot)$ denotes the $i$-th singular value and $\Sigma_A, \Sigma_X$ are diagonal matrices holding the singular values of $A$ and $X$.

Note that the inequality is actually an equality when $X$ and $A$ commute; i.e., $X$ and $A$ have the same set of eigenvectors. Therefore, the optimal solution will be

$$
X = U \mathbf{diag}\left(\mathrm{proj}_{[a, b]} \sigma_i(A)\right) U^*,
$$

where $U$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May you kindly provide a reference for the equality condition of von-Neumann's trace inequality?

Comment: I don't have an easily accessible reference at hand, but one way to verify that the condition is sufficient for equality is to simply set $X$ equal to $U D U^*$ for any diagonal matrix $D$ and $U$ being the eigenvectors of $A$ and notice that it is equal to the lower bound.

Comment: To verify the claim, have you assumed that $A=U\Sigma_A U^*$? As $\Sigma_A$ contains the singular values of $A$, and $A$ is not necessarily positive semidefinite, it seems that $U$ is not the eigenvectors of $A$. In fact, I feel the correct formula is $\Pi(A)= U \mathbf{diag}\left(\mathrm{proj}_{[a, b]} \sigma_i(A)\right) V^*$, where $A=U\Sigma_A V^*$ is the singular value decomposition of $A$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047877/singular-values-of-symmetric-matrix) a related post). Please kindly let me know if I overlooked anything.

Comment: May you kindly clarify whether you have assumed that $A=U \Sigma_A U^*$ for the SVD? I don't think this expression is true for general symmetric $A$, as it implies that $A$ is positive semidefinite. In particular, your expression of $X$ does not recover the solution in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436094/find-the-matrix-projection-of-a-symmetric-matrix-onto-the-set-of-symmetric-posit) if $A$ is negative definite.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your previous comment! Yes, I did overlook that possibility. However, in that case you can just replace the von-Neumann inequality with Fan's trace inequality, which is expressed in terms of eigenvalues instead of singular values. I can clarify in my original answer if you need more context.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I am not familiar with these trace inequalities, and I was not able to find a suitable version of Fan's trace inequality online. It seems that it is less known than the von-Neumann inequality. May you kindly clarify the details and give a reference of the inequality in your answer? I guess the final answer should replace the singular value by eigenvalues?

Comment: In particular, are you suggesting that one can have $\langle X, A\rangle \le \langle \Lambda_X, \Lambda_A\rangle $ for any positive semidefinite $X$ and any symmetric $A$, where $\Lambda_X$, $\Lambda_A$ are diagonal matrices of eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, as long as the diagonals of $\Lambda_X$ and $\Lambda_A$ are ordered in descending order.

Comment: May you give a reference for the claim?

Comment: It's Theorem 1.2.1 in ["Convex analysis and nonlinear optimization" by Borwein and Lewis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-31256-9).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much!